# WPF Button Background Issue

Tags: c#, wpf, button

I have a grid control that has 25 buttons ( the grid contains only buttons ). And for each button i set the same image like this:

```
     ImageBrush brush = new ImageBrush();
     BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();
     bitmap.BeginInit();
     bitmap.UriSource = new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/Images/notexplored.jpg", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
     bitmap.EndInit();
     brush.ImageSource = bitmap;

     foreach (UIElement uie in myGrid.Children)
     {
        var temp = uie as Button;
        temp.Background = brush;
     }
```

My problem is that now when i hover over button i get this ( its a short video with the issue): https://www.dropbox.com/s/jb8fb29lrpimue5/ButtonIssue.avi

How can i correct this? After applying the Image as a background to the button, I don't want to see the default button background(look & feel) instead of applied image, if i hover over the button.

Comment: By the way, you have enough rep to upvote now. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For ease of recreating the sample, I took 'StackPanel' as the container here. If you don't need to set the image dynamically then, I hope applying a style as shown below should get the button with look & feel as you expect, while still allowing to work with events etc., the same way you work with a typical WPF button.

```
<StackPanel x:Name="sp">
        <StackPanel.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="btnWithImageBgStyle">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                            <Border CornerRadius="5" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" >
                                <Border.Background>
                                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="pack://application:,,,/Tulip.jpg"/>
                                </Border.Background>
                                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
                            </Border>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </StackPanel.Resources>
        <Button x:Name="btn1" Width="100" Height="50" Content="Button1!" Style="{StaticResource btnWithImageBgStyle}" Click="btn1_Click"/>
        <Button x:Name="btn2" Width="100" Height="50" Content="Button2!" Style="{StaticResource btnWithImageBgStyle}"/>
        <Button x:Name="btn3" Width="100" Height="50" Content="Button3!" Style="{StaticResource btnWithImageBgStyle}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than setting the background, just add a new image as [Content](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.content.aspx) of the button. A small example:

```
var b = new Button();

var bitmap = new BitmapImage();
bitmap.BeginInit();
bitmap.UriSource = new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/floor.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
bitmap.EndInit();

var img = new Image {Source = bitmap};

b.Content = img;
```

Comment: I've set the content to image but now i have another error: Specified element is already the logical child of another element. Disconnect it first.

Comment: I`ve used the following code for setting the image: Image image = new Image();
         BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
         bi.BeginInit();
         bi.UriSource = new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/Images/notexplored.jpg", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
         bi.EndInit();
         image.Source = bi;

Comment: If i set the content to bitmap then i have the button text displayed as the string from the Uri. If i set the content to img.. i get the same error from above

Comment: Sorry, small error in the example, it's fixed now. To remove the hover effect, follow this tutorial: http://mark-dot-net.blogspot.dk/2007/07/creating-custom-wpf-button-template-in.html

Comment: Still, it doesnt work, i mean i get the error with disconnect when i set the content to image

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the control template of the button so that it does no longer respond to the `MouseOver` event. The simplest solution would be something like this

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <ContentPresenter />
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

This is an implicit style that is applied to every button that resides within the window. In the control template, you can change the look of the button and also how it behaves when it state changes (e.g. when the mouse is over the button).

Normally, the Control Template would be much more code, but in this example, you just want to have a button that shows something but leaves out all the other behavioral stuff that one can see when the mouse is over or when it is clicked. You can view the default template for Buttons in WPF here on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753328.aspx

I definitely recommend that you learn more about Styling and Templating in WPF. Here is a good starting point for this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745683.aspx

If you have questions, feel free to leave a comment.

Comment: `Grid` is redundant. Also I see no reason to put the template separately instead of directly into `Setter.Value`, especially in this trivial case.

Comment: Indeed. I just generated the code quickly with Blend during lunch break, so please forgive me.

Answer (score 1):

Buttons are overkill if you just need to display an image and respond to clicks. You can use just `ContentControl`.

Comment: If he wants to react to the `Click` event, buttons are perfectly fine, I think.

Comment: I want to use the click event to know in witch cell i clicked, this is the reason that i use the grid, and on each button is defined like:   <Button Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="0" Click="ButtonBase_OnClick"/>

Comment: `MouseDown` or `MouseUp` event will suffice. Behavior isn't that much different if there's no keyboard access planned.

Comment: for example if instead of button i use image like this: <Image Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" MouseLeftButtonDown="UIElement_OnMouseLeftButtonDown"/> why the mouse button is never executed ?

Comment: @Rock3rRullz Image is clickable only if the source picture is loaded.